# Creating buffer based on Field attribute value in QGIS Model Builder

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, qgis-processing, buffer, qgis-modeler

Working under QGIS 3.16.4 and using the Modeler, I would like to create buffers for a polygons layer.

The polygons layer includes the buffer size as an attribute (e.g. `"BUFFER_M"`) resulting from the field calculator (a previous step in the model).

[image]

Although I specified the polygons layer as the Input layer (Using algorithm output), there is **no fields available** (`NULL`) in the Expression Dialog.

[image]

I tried to fix the Distance with the expected BUFFER_M field as following: Pre-calculated Value > `"BUFFER_M"` in the Expression Dialog with no success.

[image]

All other steps in the model worked well but the buffers layer was generated with a Distance default value of 10,00 m.

Any ideas on how to specify the buffer size (Distance parameter) based on a field attribute of the input layer (vector layer)?

*NB:* the same problem when done manually as well (generated buffer of 10,00 m), however in this case the `"BUFFER_M"` field was available in the Expression Dialog.

Comment: If you want to use an attribute from another layer, how should QGIS know which buffer to use for which feature on your current layer?

Comment: Not sure to understand. The buffer size attribute is already in the table of the layer containing each features on which I would apply the buffering (with values lines per lines). Would you suppose I need to specify, e.g. : 'buffer_size by id' in the Expression Dialog?

Comment: You wrote "based on a field attribute from another vector layer" - which implies that you want to buffer layer A by values from layer B.

Comment: I recognise it was unprecise, I should have said "from a field of the input layer". Edited now.

Comment: See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/420165/88814

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the SAGA's Module ['Variable distance buffer'](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.5/shapes_tools_18.html).

In the *Buffer Distance* field, please write the name of your field, that defines the buffer size.

[image: result]