# Syntax for specifying a parameter input from an attribute field in QGIS model designer

Tags: qgis, vector, fields-attributes, qgis-modeler, azimuth

If I have a layer with an azimuth field, I can easily use that field to define the direction of the wedge buffer by clicking on the button next to the azimuth value and specifying the field type and name (see attached picture).

This option isn't available when specifying the azimuth value in QGIS's model builder (presumably because there is no layer to select the field from). I've tried using the field name as a value and in the expression builder and this doesn't work. [image: no fields are found to specify an azimuth value]

[image]

Comment: @Bera as far as I tried the problem can be reduced to a simple one: say you have a point layer with an attribute `radius`. Running `Menu Vector / Geoprocessing Tools / Buffer`, you can set the field `radius` for the buffer distance to create buffer of variably sizes, depending on the attribute value. How to do that in Modeler? I tried it in different ways, without success. Even though the question is about wedge buffer, the problem is the same. See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LZd8.png So how to create a buffer distance, based on an attribute of the input layer?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, using tools like `Wedge_buffer` or `Buffer`, setting parameters (like distance, azimuth or width) based on attribute fields does not seem to work.

For this reason, a very simple way is to use `Geometry by expression` to create geometries using QGIS expressions. The model is extremely simple as you can see on the screenshot. Use this expression to create wedgebuffers from a point layer with `azimuth` and `width` arguments based on the attribute fields `azim` and `width`:

```
wedge_buffer ($geometry, azim, width, 40)
```

[image]

*Output after running the model:*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. The model simply takes an input (point) layer and the `Create wedge buffers` algorithm. There, set `Input layer` to `Using model Input` and set it to the input created.
2. For `Azimuth` (and `Wedge width`, if you like), use the default `Value` setting from the drop down menu, at the end of the line click on `Data driven override / Edit...` and type the name of the field you want to use - and you're ready! Same output as in the screenshot of my other solution.

[image]

---

*For strange reasons, when trying it earlier, I was not able to use parameters based on attribute fields to create simple buffers or wedge buffers in a model - same problem as you or [described here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/390936/88814) (with no solution using the QGIS native algorithm).*

*However, trying it again, I was successful. I'm not sure if it has to do with the names of the attribute fields: if they are the same as the parameter itself or some functions, maybe that could cause the problem: then try using other names like `field1`, `field2`. But at least when setting it back to attribute names corresponding to the parameter name (after using it initially with another field name), it works even like that.*